# Flutter Sign in with apple failure

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, dart, signing

i implement sign in with apple on my apps, for some reason my server return error cause username length from sign in with apple didn't meet my condition and i didn't cache the information of the user. After that i update the server to remove username length requirement, but unfortunately user name and email is null? The solution i know is to stop using apple id from setting page on Iphone, is there any other solution from code? here is my code :

```
AppleSignInButton(
  style: ButtonStyle.whiteOutline,
  cornerRadius: 8,
  type: ButtonType.signIn,
  onPressed: () async {
    var isConnected = await checkConnection();
    if (!isConnected) {
        showErrorDialog(message: ErrorMessage.NO_NETWORK);
    } else {
        final AuthorizationResult result = await AppleSignIn.performRequests([
                AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])
        ]);

        if (result != null) {
            switch (result.status) {
                case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:
                    _loginWithApple(result.credential);
                    break;
                case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
                    break;
                case AuthorizationStatus.error:
                    showErrorDialog(message: result.error.localizedFailureReason);
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            showErrorDialog(message: result.status.toString(), onTap: (){});
        }
    }
},)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently Apple provides the `fullName` and `email` fields for the first sign in only. These fields will be `null` for subsequent sign ins.

However, you may opt to get the fullName through `appleIDCredential.fullName` in `didCompleteWithAuthorization` delegate method, and update the user's profile yourself.

Source: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4393#issuecomment-559012512

Comment: somehow I missed this info, then how to logout from "apple sign in" in my app?

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency to your pubspec.yaml file .

You can get the latest version from `https://pub.dev/packages/apple_sign_in`
dependencies:

```
apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
```

You can install packages from the command line:

```
$ flutter pub get
```

Alternatively, your editor might support flutter pub get like Android Studio and Visual Studio code.

1. import the “apple_sign_in.dart” to use it’s functionality .

   ```
    import 'package:apple_sign_in/apple_sign_in.dart';
   ```
2. In initState( ) of Scaffold initialise the Functionality .

   ```
   if(Platform.isIOS){             
      //check for ios if developing for both android & ios
      AppleSignIn.onCredentialRevoked.listen((_) {
      print("Credentials revoked");
    });
   }
   ```
3. Place the Apple Sign in button Specially provided for this operation .

   ```
   AppleSignInButton(
     style: ButtonStyle.black,
     type: ButtonType.continueButton,
     onPressed: appleLogIn,
   );
   ```
4. Define the appleLogIn( ) method for the sign in functionality

   ```
   if(await AppleSignIn.isAvailable()) {
       //Check if Apple SignIn isn available for the device or not
   }else{
        print('Apple SignIn is not available for your device');
   }
   ```

If Available then We can request for login

```
 if(await AppleSignIn.isAvailable()) {
    final authorizationResult result = await                                             
     AppleSignIn.performRequests([
      AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])
     ]);
  }
```

Handle the result according to your requirement

```
if(await AppleSignIn.isAvailable()) {
  final AuthorizationResult result = await AppleSignIn.performRequests([
    AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])
  ]);
  switch (result.status) {
    case AuthorizationStatus.authorized:                                     
       print(result.user);//All the required credentials
    case AuthorizationStatus.error:
      print("Sign in failed: ${result.error.localizedDescription}");
      break;
    case AuthorizationStatus.cancelled:
      print('User cancelled');
      break;
  }
}
```

You can send the credentials to your backend on whatever you want to do .

Comment: For me this step is not returning any result. I have checked my signing capabilities , certificates are all fine in developer portal. Anyone else facing this issue 

await AppleSignIn.performRequests([
    AppleIdRequest(requestedScopes: [Scope.email, Scope.fullName])